# Can we customize Alfresco content replication service?

Tags: repository, alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to migrate All content from one alfresco repository to other.
Here my old Alfresco repository contents are in file system and i want to migrate it to other Alfresco repository which is there in S3 Bucket of amazon cloud.

The reason why i want to customize replication service is, i want to do some validation before migration. and i want to bifurcate content based on content type. because some other logic is already written in new alfresco repository to      create different folder structure for all content as per the content type.

So in this case i don't want existing folder structure. i just want all content with metadata.

Can i customize the replication service as per my requirement?
Please help me with this.
If we are not able to customize then also provide the alternative way to do the same..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Please reply, if anyone did this before. and whether it is possible or not

Comment: Hello Experts, can you at list tell me whether customization is possible on not??

Comment: Alfresco is open source, so you can customise pretty much anything you want!

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks for reply...............

Comment: Source code at https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition-old/blob/master/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/replication/ReplicationServiceImpl.java though you might actually need to customise at the Transfer Service layer, that's https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition-old/blob/master/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/transfer/TransferServiceImpl.java

Comment: Hi, replication is not advised for moving bulk contents to another server. One suggestion is to write a webscript to get the required details of all the contents, write to an excel sheet and use the same to create new contents in next server.

Comment: Or you can backup the server 1 contents and upload to server 2, then create a script to migrate the contents according to the requirements.

Comment: @Sheljithkrishnan What exactly you want me to write in excel sheet, can you please Elaborate. So i can follow that. You can also put your assumptions as a answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you want only the content details, i would suggest you to create a webscript to export all the details and store in excel. Then you can use this excel to create contents in another server according to the content type.

Consider you have two types of contents with 5Properites(Name,Type,Property1,Property2,Property3). So in script, get the content details through search serive and store it in excel sheet(a row for each contents). You can create different xls for different models also. Then in new server write a script which will read each row and create contents in new folder structure according to the content type.
[image]

Comment: Your suggestion is good, but it will only take care of meta-data. Can you suggest any way to migrate actual contents also. Means i want to migrate all files from repository without maintaining folder structure in new repository.

Comment: If its just cm:content field, you can store even that in xls. But if the you have some pdf or other files, i would suggest you to go for backup the server 1 contents and load it to server 2. Then write a webscript to identify the contents and move to new folder structure, then delete the old folder structure.

Comment: there are Lakhs of contents are there in My Old Repository, So where do i take backup. Can you please provide any sample code or webscript.

Comment: Hi, you can follow
https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-4794-backup-and-restore or 
http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/ch-backup-restore.html

Comment: @ Sheljith krishnan Thanks